# Segmentation fault with recursive pointers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to use a treePrint function to print a tree, but I am having problems with printing the hard coded tree.
 It gives me a segmentation fault when it is recursively called and I am not sure how to fix it. 
I think that the problem lies with the way I'm using pointers but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to fix it.

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct node
{
  char* objectName;
  char* question;
  struct node *yes_ptr; 
  struct node *no_ptr; 
};




void nodePrint(struct node *ptr)
{

  printf("objectName: %s\n", ptr->objectName );
  printf("question: %s\n", ptr->question );
}

void treePrint(struct node *ptr)
{
  printf("yes pointer\n" );

  if (ptr == NULL)
  {
    //do nothing
  }
  else
  {
    if (strcmp( ptr->objectName, "Q") == 0)
    {
      printf("question: %s\n", ptr->question );
      //now print the yes and no subtrees:

      treePrint((ptr->yes_ptr));
      treePrint(ptr->no_ptr);
    }
      else
    { // ptr is an object

      printf("objectName: %s\n", ptr->objectName );

  }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct node *nodes[20];

  struct node *node1 = malloc(sizeof(nodes));
  node1->objectName = "Q";
  node1->question = "Does it have a tail?";
  node1->yes_ptr = nodes[0]+1;
  node1->no_ptr = nodes[0]+2;
  nodes[0] = node1;

  struct node *node2 = malloc(sizeof(nodes));
  node2->objectName = "Q";
  node2->question = "Does it like to chase mice?";
  node2->yes_ptr = nodes[0]+2;
  node2->no_ptr = nodes[0]+4;
  nodes[1] = node2;
  treePrint(nodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: Note: `nodes[0] + 4` does _not_ give you the pointer stored in `nodes[4]`. Also, if you have links to nodes 2 and 4, but don't define them, make sure that they are `NULL` at least.

Comment: `node1->yes_ptr = nodes[0]+1;` is cause of seg. fault.

Answer (score 0):

Your pointer arithmetic isn't correct. Here:

```
nodes[0] + 1;
```

you refer to the node right after `node[0]`. That would only work if the node were part of a contiguous array, which isn't true: It is a single node on the heap.

You could fix this by referring to just `nodes[1]` instead. Tat meas that you should first initialise all nodes to `NULL`:

```
 struct node *nodes[20] = {NULL};
```

in order to catch dangling nodes. For example, you refer to node 4 in your code, which you haven't defined yet.

If you want to use this approach, you must define the nodes backwards, that is you must define the children before the parent, so that the parent can refer to the actual node. This method also requires you to free all nodes at the end of the program.

That's probably not what you want. Instead, make your array an array of nodes, not an array of pointers to nodes:

```
struct node node[20];
```

Then you can use pointer arithmetic to create a pointerv to nodes in this array. Make sure that you explicitly use `NULL` where there is no link:

```
node[0].objectName = "Q";
node[0].question = "Does it have a tail?";
node[0].yes_ptr = node + 1;
node[0].no_ptr = NULL;
```

Note that you don't explicitly allocate anything and hence don't need to worry about freeing the memory. That's the point of hard-coding your tree.

You can even do better by initialising the tree straight away without explicitly filling in all the values by hand:

```
struct node node[] = {
    {"Q", "Does it have a tail?",           node + 1,   node + 2},
    {"Q", "Does it like to chase mice?",    node + 4,   node + 3},
    {"A", "It's a Manx cat!",               NULL,       NULL},
    {"A", "It's a musophobic cat!",         NULL,       NULL},
    {"A", "It's just a normal cat!",        NULL,       NULL}        
};
```